# AWS autoscaling - custom scale in process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a need to customize scale in event. Specifically I have to trigger scale in event in a controlled way - decrease desired size by 1 and terminate one specific instance. This will be done from AWS SDK.

What is the correct order to issue commands:
A) terminate instance, decrease desired size.
B) decrease desired size, terminate instance.

I want to avoid situation where Autoscalling will terminate another instance when desired size parameter changes.

Answer (score 1):

Wading through SDK documentation found exactly what I need. There is API call to terminate an instance in autoscaling group and decrease desired size at the same time.

Documentation and example here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/AutoScaling/Client.html#terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group-instance_method